# Target File Name with Current Week

Tags: c#, .net, nslog

I want to name the target file with week : 08-15 September 2014. Log file that is time/size limited > 7 days with max 5 MB, How can I achieve that?

Thanks,
Attiqe

Comment: C Evenhuis, thanks for you comment. I am already using nlog as it's mentioned in the tag. So I have tried and that's why I am here.

Comment: My bad, perhaps it's time for me to get glasses.